# Input filename into jar from windows batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, batch-processing

I want to input a file into my jar after it is executed from batch file.

I wrote the following batch code.

```
@echo off

 set path=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin

 java -jar E:\ER\er_v.3.3.17.jar
```

The above code is working fine. However, after the jar file is executed I need to feed another file for it to run successfully.

I want something like this

```
@echo off

 set path=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin

 java -jar E:\ER\er_v.3.3.17.jar

 echo E:\Run.xml
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Pass it as an argument?  `java -jar E:\ER\er_v.3.3.17.jar "E:\Run.xml"`

Comment: feed it meaning - does it expect a file name of an xml file or the contents of the xml file? How does it expect to get either - by reading from stdin or some other way?

Comment: It reads the XML filename not the contents.

Comment: @bmorris591 Argument wont work because I want to input the file name after the jar is executed.

Comment: Okay. Pipe it in then, on UNIX that would be `java -jar E:\ER\er_v.3.3.17.jar < echo "E:\Run.xml"`.

Comment: Its not working. I tried that.

Comment: write it to a file for your java script.

Comment: You mean write the "E:\Run.xml" into another file and then open it from batch?

Comment: No, write the arguments in a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.  I tested this and it works.

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: if java.exe is not in %path%
for %%I in (java.exe) do if "%%~$PATH:I" equ "" (
    set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin"
)

echo E:\Run.xml| java -jar E:\ER\er_v.3.3.17.jar
```

This passes "E:\Run.xml" to the stdin of `java -jar etc`.

Comment: @John - What is stopping, the batch script or the Java applet?  The script is supposed to sleep for 5 seconds before sending the filename keyboard strokes.  That's to give enough time for the Java applet to load and be ready for input.  Modify the `5000` as needed, and make sure the Java applet keeps its focus until after the keys are sent to it.  The `SendKeys` method sends its keystrokes to whatever window happens to have focus.

Comment: Java Applet is opening up but the sendkeys is not working I guess. I increased the the time to 0 Seconds but it sill is behaving in the same way

Comment: Feel free to edit your comments instead of piling corrections on top of each other :)  Anyway, yes, `WSH.Sleep` is shorthand for `WScript.Sleep`.  What's the title of the Java Applet window?  Maybe I'll try adding [AppActivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyz95fhy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) immediately before `SendKeys`.

Comment: I don't see any name on the applet. Its like CMD with Java Logo. I will edit this comment. How to send a screenshot?

Comment: @John - Does the Java applet window have a prompt expecting user input?  Is the console window's main window pane or input field or whatever appropriate focused as it should be?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27895/discussion-between-john-and-rojo)